# Trying to connect my Node.js app to Heroku PostgreSQL DB. Struggling to connect to the DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, pg-promise

I'm relatively new to Node, Postres etc. I followed a guide I used on a similar project ~5 years ago, and it isn't working. I also tried various solutions to similar questions and none have worked.

It seems most people fail to connect because Heroku has a problem with `process.env.DATABASE_URL`, but I've tried all sorts of ways of manually entering that data and it still fails to connect.

I'm able to connect to this database and run queries from powershell, however it never works through though this Node method.

Error code that Heroku gives me when trying to connect to DB through an endpoint:
`at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/demosql" host=<host> request_id=bec5a277-9c18-48a5-8742-fc26429ab fwd="73.254.66.157" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https`

Index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
pgp.pg.defaults.ssl = true;

let ssl = {rejectUnauthorized: false};

const config = {
  host: 'ec2-54-225-234-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: 5432,
  database: '<db>',
  user: '<user>',
  password: '<password>',
  max: 30, // use up to 30 connections
  ssl: ssl,
};
const db = pgp(config);


if (!db) {
  console.log(
    "FAILED! Follow the intructions and set your DATABASE_URL correctly"
  );
  process.exit(1);
} else {
    console.log('connected to ' + config.host)
}


app.get("/test", (req, res) => {

    console.log('testing')
    db
      .any("SELECT * Demo LIMIT 10")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .then(() => {
        db.$pool.end();
      });
  });

app.get("/demosql", (req, res) => {
  db.manyOrNone("SELECT Text FROM Demo")
    //If successful, run function passed into .then()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send({
        success: true,
        names: data,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.send({
        success: false,
        error: error,
      });
    });
});
```

package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "form-data": "^2.3.2",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "npm": "^5.7.1",
    "pg": "^7.4.1",
    "pg-promise": "^8.1.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
...
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Postgres [enforces](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2035) SSL for all client connections.  You might try the equivalent of sslmode=require for your connection string.